# Saving an uploaded image to directory using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking for an effective method for saving an uploaded image to the assets folder. The code in place is as follows.

```
@profile.profileimage = "app/assets/images/" + @profile.userid

      if not File.exists?(@profile.profileimage) 
        FileUtils::mkdir_p(@profile.profileimage)
       else

       end
```

It will check if the directory is present and if it isn't it will make the directory. I am just unsure what is best way of saving the image to the folder. I see the method where you grab the image from its url, but I do not think that would work for this scenario.

I have tried using this method, however I know I am doing it wrong and I am unsure how to properly use the open method. currenty it is throwing a

> Errno::EISDIR in ProfilesController#create Is a directory @ rb_sysopen

here is the open I am trying to use...

```
File.open(@profile.profileimage) do |f|
          @image = f
        end
```

@profile.profileimage is the directory path I want to save it to.

Comment: Why do you want to save your image in the asset folder? is there a specific reason for this ?

Comment: I always use the paperclip gem (though there's another called carrierwave which i heard is pretty good.): https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Comment: Yes, since I am saving the image name in the database, I will refer to it at the location app/assets/images/userid, for when I want to display it to the page.

Comment: I do use Paperclip too. It saves images inside system folder. You put in assets/images only the permanent stuff: your logo, ... Not sure you can save images in that very folder. Is there any reason why you want to locate images in that folder ?

Comment: you don't need to know the location of the image. just use the path or url method such as : <%= image_tag f.image.url(:big) %> for the 'big' style in this example (provided your image is already saved)

Comment: The files in the `assets` folder or its subfolders are not served by rails even the configuration `serve_static_assets` (or `serve_static_files` in Rails 5) is turned on. Nor should they be served by the reverse proxy (e.g. Nginx). Those files do not survive capistrano redeployments. For these reasons, you should NEVER put user uploaded files in the `assets` folder.

Comment: @Aetherus okay thank-you I didn't know that

Comment: Joshua, I saw your edit. But i am not sure I understand it. Can you tell us a few things. What is your model name with a paperclip attachment in it ? Have you managed to save images in that model ? Have you properly set your model with `has_attached_file` and `validates_attachment` methods ? ...

Comment: Sorry, I am pretty new with ruby so I may be missing some things. I am not using paperclip, I am using carrierwave.I have not managed to save images, I am doing this processing in my controller for the profile page when creating a new profile. I do not have the has_attached_file and validates_attachment

Comment: As I am using Paperclip I cannot really help you. Just check Carrierwave tutorials and follow them closely. You will set this up easy.

Comment: has_attached_file and validates_attachment is only for Paperclip